Вопрос по архитектуре FSD (Feature Slice Design)
Осваиваю Feature Slice Design и пытаюсь применить архитектуру, методологию FSD на своём личном проекте.
В приложении бывают разные тогглы, переключалки и тд, вот у меня сейчас есть тоггл по переключению темы, и кнопка по коллапсу сайдбара, по сути это фичи, верно? Но у них должно быть какое то свое состояние,  а состояние мы храним в сущностях, то есть мне определить их сначала в сущностях со срезом redux состояния и переключения, а потом переопределить в фичах? И так может быть много таких компонентов у которых должно быть свое состояние, и для каждого делать отдельное хранилище, боюсь в корневом редьюсере куда все потом подключать получится каша... Или сделать отдельное хранилище, которое не относится к бизнес логике, чисто управление приложением, но где тогда его расположить по FSD, и не будет ли это противоречить архитектуре...

как задать хороший вопрос. начните с заголовка

в документации FSD сказано, что features - это переиспользуемый функционал для сущностей. вряд ли кнопка коллапса сайдбара будет когда-то переиспользоваться. то есть, в данной ситуации Вы пытаетесь вынести что-то в features только ради того, чтобы "что-то куда-то" вынести, а не получить пользу от методологии.
тоже самое и с тогглом для темы. где еще будет переиспользоваться этот тоггл?

некоторые люди, которые слишком часто работают с FSD, советуют сначала весь UI и логику писать сразу в pages/widgets. и если (и только) случается ситуация, когда нужно переиспользовать то, что уже написано в pages/widgets, вырезать и перемещать на слой ниже - features и entities
